# Prevent min > max values on input type=number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input numbers (min and max). Is there a way to prevent user inserting values like min > max?

```
<input type="number" class="inputMin" placeholder="Min.">

<input type="number" class="inputMax" placeholder="Max.">
```

Comment: show you tried code.

Comment: @Burki that was totally unnecessary. If i am not sharing any code that means I did not find anything otherwise I wouldn't have been asking here.

Comment: Was it? Well. You might want to take a look at the help session. The way you asked your question would have been a reason to close it. I was trying a less aggressive way to point that out, but well, in the end it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you can do this.

One option is whenever min is changed, if it is greater than max, change it to equal max, like this:

```
$('.inputMin').on('change', function() {
    var max = parseFloat($('.inputMax').val());                                     
    var min = parseFloat($('.inputMin').val());
    if (min > max) {
        $('.inputMin').val(max);
    }
});
```

or the opposite case when you change max:

```
$('.inputMax').on('change', function() {
    var max = parseFloat($('.inputMax').val());                                     
    var min = parseFloat($('.inputMin').val());
    if (min > max) {
        $('.inputMin').val(max);
    }
});
```

Another option is to display an error, either when the form is submitted, or dynamically as the user changes the input.

There are a number of javascript libraries that allow you to do dynamic validation very easily. Check out [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), and how to use it for [form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried that but doesn't seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/78vxko4u/

Comment: Forgot to include `parseFloat`. Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery, you can try this :

(and you have to change `class` to `id`)

```
var min = document.getElementById("inputMin");
var max = document.getElementById("inputMax");

function check() {
    if (min.value > max.value) {
        min.value = max.value;
    }
};

min.addEventListener("input", check, false);
max.addEventListener("input", check, false);
```

You can try it [there](http://jsfiddle.net/dzeyzj9d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters `min` and `max` like:

```
<form>
  Quantity (between 1 and 5):
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
</form>
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp (Input Type: number)

Also you can use Javascript to check if the value is `>= min_number` and `<= max_number`, but both are client side scripts, which can be bypassen with editing the html part.

You also need a server-side check so you can be sure it's within the range.